# Positioning static blocks side by side on a cms page

Tags: blocks, cms

First of all I should say I am not a web designer because I think my problem is really simple to solve but I don't know how:

[image: positioning/formatting static blocks how should it look like]

I created static blocks with these images but I can't bring it to this position.

Comment: can you explain in details ?

Comment: can you share your current status? And whcih theme are you using?

Comment: Sure, the images which are in static blocks should display on the homepage and they contain hyperlinks to the defined cms-links.

I could after trying too long only place the image/block with the text /link shop on the left side but all the other images/blocks are not at the right side when I place them rather they are placed from top the bottom and that is not positioning which I want.

Comment: The theme I am using is a custom theme from templatemonster which needs a little customising for me, its called one day/theme743. The image which I posted here in my problem is created with photoshop its not a screenshot from the site. And my current status is explained above now :)

Comment: It's nice of you that you want to reward people who help you but I removed this part of your question because it makes it look like a job offering, which is not suitable for the Q&A format of this site. Actually as it stands it's hard to help you, without exchanging more information about your site, because it's not "really simple to solve" but will need custom CSS tailored to the theme you are using, positioning like this is not possible in the CMS itself. You'll probably have more success with an actual job offering, somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code block, and use it as reference:

```
<div style="width:100%;float:left;">
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        //here you can place left image block
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
            <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
                //right image block position left 1
            </div>
            <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
                //right image block position right 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
            <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
                //right image block position left 2
            </div>
            <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
                //right image block position right 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can call static blocks where I have placed comments.
Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Okay I have tried but it still wont work. Is there any extension to make this easier? I am trying this for a very long time and it wont work either I am working with the false files or I dont know...